# NopCommerce custom api methods are not showing in swaggerUi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, nopcommerce

I am working on nopCommerce webApi plugin, when I add new methods to api plugin.
For example I add **GetTest()** method to product api controller. It does not show in the list of methods which are shown in swaggerUI.

As you can see **GetTest()** method is not available in SwaggerUi List.

[image]

I have also added the web api route in the **startup.cs**.

[image]

Here is my api **GetTest()** method.

[image]

here is my **SwaggerUi** configuration in **Startup.cs**.

```
config.Filters.Add(new ServerErrorHandlerAttribute());

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetTest",
            routeTemplate: "api/products/GetTest",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "GetTest" });

        // The default route templates for the Swagger docs and swagger-ui are "swagger/docs/{apiVersion}" and "swagger/ui/index#/{assetPath}" respectively.
        config
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "RESTful API documentation");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\Plugins\Nop.Plugin.Api\Nop.Plugin.Api.XML", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                // We need this filter to exclude some of the API endpoints from the documentation i.e /OAuth/Authorize endpoint
                c.DocumentFilter<ExcludeEnpointsDocumentFilter>();
                c.OperationFilter<RemovePrefixesOperationFilter>();
                c.OperationFilter<ChangeParameterTypeOperationFilter>();
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
                var currentAssemblyName = currentAssembly.GetName().Name;

                c.InjectJavaScript(currentAssembly, string.Format("{0}.Scripts.swaggerPostPutTryItOutButtonsRemoval.js", currentAssemblyName));
            });

        app.UseWebApi(config);

        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(EngineContext.Current.ContainerManager.Container);

        // Configure the asp.net webhooks.
        ConfigureWebhooks(config);
```

Please guide me a little I am new to SwaggerUI.

Comment: A couple of possible reasons. Your startup is not configuring swagger correctly. There are duplicate methods in that class with exactly the same name.

Comment: @lloyd i've added the configurations of SwaggerUi please have a look,
and there is only single method of GetTest in the ProductsController.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a response type like all the other HttpGet methods have

eg.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(MyTestResult))]
```

I could not test this, but this seems to be the only difference to the existing methods.